# What determines the size of a saved object in R?

Tags: r, memory, workspace

When I save an object from R using save(), what determines the size of the saved file? Clearly it is not the same (or close to) the size of the object determined by object.size().

Example:
I read a data frame and saved it using

```
snpmat=read.table("Heart.txt.gz",header=T)
save(snpmat,file="datamat.RData")
```

The size of the file datamat.RData is 360MB.

```
> object.size(snpmat)
4998850664 bytes        #Much larger
```

Then I performed some regression analysis and obtained another data frame adj.snpmat of same dimensions (6820000 rows and 80 columns).

```
> object.size(adj.snpmat)
4971567760 bytes
```

I save it using

```
> save(adj.snpmat,file="adj.datamat.RData")
```

Now the size of the file adj.datamat.RData is 3.3GB. I'm confused why the two files are so different in size while the object.size() gives similar sizes. Any idea about what determines the size of the saved object is welcome.

Some more information:

```
> typeof(snpmat)
[1] "list"

> class(snpmat)
[1] "data.frame"

> typeof(snpmat[,1])
[1] "integer"

> typeof(snpmat[,2])
[1] "double"         #This is true for all columns except column 1

> typeof(adj.snpmat)
[1] "list"

> class(adj.snpmat)
[1] "data.frame"

> typeof(adj.snpmat[,1])
[1] "character"

> typeof(adj.snpmat[,2])
[1] "double"         #This is true for all columns except column 1
```

Comment: The saved `.Rdata` file is compressed and should thus be smaller.  How much smaller will depend on the compression algorithm and your data.

Comment: In my example, what might be the reason?
In other words, can you tell me what aspects of the data affect it?

Comment: @Pratyay What do you know about compression?  It would probably be beneficial to read up on it as that's basically what you're asking. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression

Comment: @Dason Thanks. I went through the link. But I still do not understand how it works specifically in R. What data types are compressed better? Also, in my example, the two data frames had everything similar. Why is there such a huge difference in compression?
Also, is there any tricks to generate smaller files while saving objects? eg using some particular data types or so?

Comment: I have the same issue with a variable around 5Mb with `object.size` which become 750Mb after `save` !

Comment: If you have an example where the serialized size is much bigger than object.size, it might be interesting to post it with code/data. One particular documented situation where this can happen is when data is hidden in an environment - environment content is excluded from object.size calculation.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the only data for which I encountered this. I tried to produce a small reproducible example, but it didn't work. Can you tell me how to check if there is any hidden component? I am not sure if I fully understood about that. Since you said it is documented, can you lead me to such documentation?

Comment: I was referring just to `?object.size` (environments and external pointers are excluded). To exclude the impact of compression from your experiments, you can use `compress` argument of `save`.

Answer (score 0):

Your matrices are very different and therefore compress very differently.

SNP data contains only a few values (e.g., 1 or 0) and is also very sparse.  This means that is very easy to compress.  For example, if you had a matrix of all zeros, you could think of compressing the data by specifying a single value (0) as well as the dimensions.

Your regression matrix contains many different types of values, and are also real numbers (I'm assuming p-values, coefficients, etc.)  This makes it much less compressible.